# Filtering a list of pandas dataframes to only include row indexes ending in a

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a list of pd dataframes (1377 of them). I need to split each dataframe into cases where the row index ends in a and where the row index ends in c.

I have looked at other stack overflow pages where this is suggested

```
(df.iloc[all_dfs[0].index.str.endswith('a',na=False)])
```

however this transposes my dataframe and then reduces the number of rows (previously columns before transposing)

Here is a short section from my first dataframe if that helps.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass tuple of test values to [`str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(5)}, 
                   index=['_E031a','_E031b','_E031c','_E032a','_E032b'])

df1 = df[df.index.str.endswith(('a', 'c'),na=False)]
print (df1)
        a
_E031a  0
_E031c  2
_E032a  3
```

Or get last values of strings by indexing `[-1]` and test membership by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df1 = df[df.index.str[-1].isin(['a', 'c'])]
print (df1)
        a
_E031a  0
_E031c  2
_E032a  3
```

For looping in list of DataFrames use:

```
all_dfs = [df[df.index.str.endswith(('a', 'c'),na=False)] for df in all_dfs]
```

If want only test `a`:

```
all_dfs = [df[df.index.str.endswith('a',na=False)] for df in all_dfs]
```

Comment: this works for an individual dataframe really well, thank you. But for looping through my list of dataframes im using achan[i]= all_dfs2[i][all_dfs2[i].index.str[-1].isin(['a'])] where achan is my new list of dataframes and all_dfs2 is my original list of dataframes. This line is in the loop for i in range (len(all_dfs2)). When I run this is get IndexError: list assignment index out of range, any ideas?